# effective query than AND operator

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]I would like to know that is there any other effective way or query to get the desired output for the below query with AND operators because if I run this below query I am getting 0 counts. but according to the data warehouse report, there are many records for the below combination.

Any alternative way to search?

```
select Count(*)
FROM   Cst_Cust_Attributes
WHERE  ATTRIBUTE_VALUE = 'REG'
       AND ATTRIBUTE_VALUE = 'GUEST'
       AND ATTRIBUTE_VALUE = 'EVENT'
```

Comment: Sorry, but most probably your query should look like select count(*) FROM Cst_Cust_Attributes WHERE 
ATTRIBUTE_VALUE ='REG' OR
ATTRIBUTE_VALUE ='GUEST'OR
ATTRIBUTE_VALUE ='EVENT'

Comment: There is no single row for which ATTRIBUTE_VALUE is 'REG' *and* 'GUEST' *and* 'EVENT'. It can be only one of these values in one row. You want `OR` instead. Or simpler `WHERE attribute_value IN ('REG', 'GUEST', EVENT')`.

Comment: no i want all the customer records in these AND combinations and not in OR condition.

Comment: `WHERE´ looks at one row at a time, so naturally you cannot find anything, if you demand the row to match two (or even three) contradicting conditions.

Comment: So you want to find all the customers who have all three attributes? It would be helpful to edit your question to include the structure of this table, with sample data and expected results. Including the column that identifies which customer each attribute belongs to. (You're probably looking for aggregation and the `having` clause though...)

Comment: This looks awfully like a key/value table. This would consist of some group key (the customer ID?), a keyword and a value. Your query hence seems to be missing a lot, if you only look at the attribute_value. But that's just guessing. Show us the table strcture and some sample data. And explain thoroughly what you actually want to achieve. Optimally also showing us a sample result.

Comment: This indeed looks like an EAV model ...

Comment: yes ,i want to find all the customers who have all 3 attributes

Comment: @ThorstenKettner iam using oracle database

Comment: Oracle is your *database management system* (DBMS). You are using a *database* with a table in it that is called Cst_Cust_Attributes. We don't know this table. We don't know what columns it have and what its rows represent. You need to tell and show us.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner iam attaching the table structure in the top

Comment: Providing code instead of images of code helps to get much faster recommendations from the community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table has a `cust_id` column, you seem to want something like:

```
SELECT cust_id, count(*)
FROM Cst_Cust_Attributes
WHERE attribute_value IN ('REG', 'GUEST', 'EVENT')
GROUP BY cust_id
HAVING count(*) = 3
```

That would list all customers which have all three attribute values. You could leave the count out of the column list if you don't want to see that; it doesn't need to be there, the important bit is having it in the `having` clause.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=2fe833c040ac2d18b9e5b89db6eb3167) with very basic made-up data.

As noted in comments, no single row in this table can have more than one value for the column so you need to look for rows with *any* of the three values - with `or` or `in`.

The aggregation then counts how many of those values were found for each customer (see the first query in the db<>fiddle), which will include any customers with *any* of those three.

Finally the `having` clause filters out any of those customers who had fewer than three of the values. If the count is 3 for a customer then they had three rows in the table which matched the values you were looking for.

(This also assumes they can only have each attribute value once - if there could be duplicates within a customer then that could be handled by modifying what is counted to `HAVING count(distinct attribute_value) = 3` - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ca74d3e706a2d3f9a8a6f51a1dc53c3b) with duplicates.)

> i need join another column mail_id from another table cst_mail

You could just add a join in the main query:

```
SELECT cca.cust_id, cm.mail_id
FROM Cst_Cust_Attributes cca
LEFT JOIN cst_mail cm ON cm.cust_id = cca.cust_id
WHERE cca.attribute_value IN ('REG', 'GUEST', 'EVENT')
GROUP BY cca.cust_id
HAVING count(distinct cca.attribute_value) = 3
```

Or turn that into an inline view (or CTE) and join to that:

```
SELECT tmp.cust_id, cm.mail_id
FROM (
  SELECT cust_id
  FROM Cst_Cust_Attributes
  WHERE attribute_value IN ('REG', 'GUEST', 'EVENT')
  GROUP BY cust_id
  HAVING count(distinct attribute_value) = 3
) tmp
LEFT JOIN cst_mail cm ON cm.cust_id = tmp.cust_id
```

Comment: this seems to be matching and getting all the customer records who are having all 3 tags

Comment: can you please explain how??

Comment: @HappyMan - added more explanation, hope that helps.

Comment: You might want `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT attribute_value) = 3` otherwise you can get rows with 3 `'REG'` values and none of the others.

Comment: Yes, that's what the last paragraph and linked fiddle showed; but I've edited to include the modified clause to make it clearer.

Comment: @AlexPoole  i need join another column mail_id from another table cst_mail using joins.to mention the corresponding email id for the cust_id.please tell where to insert the left join.please edit in the above

Comment: @HappyMan - that's really a separate issue and question, but it's pretty trivial so I've added two simple ways.